# Random empty request response from AJAX causing a JSON parsererror

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm encountering an issue that is baffling me. When connecting to a database, through a AJAX JSON request, **sometimes** (randomly) it returns an empty XML string instead of the expected JSON. The JavaScript function is given below:

```
function MyFunction(location_list){

var dictTable = {}
for (n in location_list) {
    var restRequestURL = '/geoserver/rest/api/v1/locations/'+location_list[n];
    $.ajax({
        url : restRequestURL,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {},
        tryCount : 0,  // Tried this as a workaround
        retryLimit : 3,  // Tried this as a workaround
        success: function(response){
            dictTable[response.typeString] = anotherFunction(response);
            if (Object.keys(dictTable).length == location_list.length) {
                yetAnotherFunction(dictTable, location_list);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                    // Brute force workaround
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    if (textStatus == "parsererror") {
                        this.tryCount++;
                        if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
                            //try again
                            $.ajax(this);
                            return;
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    if (xhr.status == 500) {
                        console.log("Server Error 500...");
                    } else {
                        console.log(xhr.status);
                    }
                }
    })
}
}
```

The JSON is correctly returned in most requests, and everything goes as expected (anotherFunction and yetAnotherFunction are triggered). But in some not-so-rare cases (1 in 10 or so), the request returns an empty XML object instead of the expected JSON.

Consequently, the AJAX call fails on a "parsererror", since it's expecting a JSON but getting an empty XML. So, all my requests return with a successful code (200, OK status), but the response is sometimes incorrect, as if the database didn't have time to respond or mixed things up and just said "whatever, here you go anyway".

Error data object:

```
{
  "readyState": 4,
  "responseText": "",
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK"
}
```

The Network tab from the Firefox developer console (File 120 being the specific request that is tried twice in that case with the workaround):

```
Status   Method   File  Domain  Cause  Type  Transferred  Size
200       GET     120   domain   xhr    xml    145 B      0 B
200       GET     120   domain   xhr   json    1.08 KB   2.77 KB
```

I must say that I'm at a loss here as to what is going on. Could you suggest an approach to debug this problem, or do you see anything obvious that would be causing this strange behavior?

Comment: The response type is being handled by a back-end. Your Ajax request most likely has nothing to do with. Review the back-end part.

Comment: One thing to note though is that browser requests (manually inputting the request in the browser) always return the JSON correctly. Maybe a timeout issue? (though I have tested doing a request at a time in AJAX and still encounter the problem) I don't have direct access to the database but will see what logs I can get out. The randomness of it makes it hard to debug for me.